# Sql select - how select from other table if is null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a view which returns me some nulls values for the columns b.emissor and B.indexador. In case of null, I need to find this values first in table TB_CAD_RF and, if still nulls, I need to query TB_CAD_RF_2.
I try the logic below but its not working. Also tried to think something with case statements but cant figure it out.

Anyone could help me please?

```
select A.NM_ATIVO, B.EMISSOR, B.INDEXADOR from VW_POSICAO as A
LEFT JOIN
TB_CAD_RF B on A.NM_ATIVO = B.CODIGO
where a.NM_EMISSOR is null
as C LEFT JOIN (
select C.EMISSOR, C.INDEXADOR from TB_CAD_RF_2 as D ON B.NM_ATIVO = C.CODIGO where C.EMISSOR is null)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE( first.choice, second.choice, third.choice) as a
FROM
  first
  LEFT JOIN second on first.id = second.id
  LEFT JOIN third on second.id = third.id
```

Coalesce returns the first non null passed into it, scanning from left to right

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way. Always join both and coalesce the fields in the order of desired results.

```
select A.NM_ATIVO, 
    EMISSOR = COALESCE(A.EMISSOR,B.EMISSOR), 
    INDEXADOR=COALESCE(A.INDEXADOR,B.INDEXADOR)
from VW_POSICAO  A
LEFT JOIN TB_CAD_RF B on A.NM_ATIVO = B.CODIGO
LEFT JOIN TB_CAD_RF_2 D ON A.NM_ATIVO =D.CODIGO
```

Answer (score 2):

Case when ISNULL((select * from table1) , (select * from table2) ) else select...

ISNULL is like an IIF statement, but if query field returns a null value, it tries the alternate query or you can set an alternate value.

Syntax may be a bit off, haven't written this query in a while, but it should put you on the right path. Google sql ISNULL